# Is a "block padding" exception expected when using the wrong key during decryption?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, aes, crypto++

I am currently working on a password manager for my own and the encryption process of the database is working perfectly fine comparing the result I get with test vector.

To decrypt the ciphertext, I am trying to use code I found on the web but if I give the program the wrong decryption key, I get an exception. I wanted to know if it is safe to catch this exception or if it's something I'm doing wrong.

The code I have is :

```cpp
CryptoPP::CBC_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Decryption aesDecryption;
aesDecryption.SetKeyWithIV(derivedKey, sizeof(derivedKey), initVector);

// The StreamTransformationFilter removes
//  padding as required.
CryptoPP::StringSource ss(encryptedString, true,
    new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(aesDecryption,
        new CryptoPP::StringSink(decryptedData)
    ) // StreamTransformationFilter
); // StringSource
```

where derivedKey is an `unsigned char*` generated by PBKDF2, `initVector` is also an `unsigned char*`, `encryptedString` is a string containing the data I want to decrypt and `decryptedData` is a string to put the decrypted data.

If I execute this code using the right `derivedKey`, everything works fine. But if I try using a wrong `derivedKey`, I get the following error from Crypto++:

```
StreamTransformationFilter: invalid PKCS #7 block padding found
```

I'd like to know if this is normal when the key given to the `StreamTransformationFitler` isn't the right one, or if this error can occur from something else.

Comment: Yes its expected. The behavior is the basis of the padding oracles in SSL/TLS (and other protocols and schemes). You should use an authenticated encryption mode. Also see [Authenticated Encryption](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Authenticated_Encryption) on the Crypto++ wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can happen with wrong keys.

If the correct key gives this exception too, your code is wrong, but apparently this isn't happening.

But note that this exception is *not* guaranteed to occur with wrong keys. Some data with some wrong key will generate the exception, others won't (then the decrypted data is garbage). If you want a reliable way to dedect wrong keys, you'll an additional "checksum" part, just in a secure way. Eg. CBC-MACs with a different key.

What this exception means:
AES works with data blocks of 16 byte size. If the data length is no a multiple of 16 (eg. 16, 32, 48 is ok, but not 1, 20, 45 etc.), then it's necessary to add some byte to your original data before encrypting it, so that it becomes a multiple of 16. This is called padding. After decrypting, this padding data must be removed again to get your original data.
The "problem" is now that when encrypting, the library uses specific byte values for it's padding data; and after decrypting, it checks if the values match. If not, you'll get this exception. And with a wring key, giving wrong data when decrypting, it's unlikely that the padding part is correct.

Comment: @zaph How do you get the "1 in 256 chance" (given that the padding has anything between 1 and 16 byte)? ... And, imho, independent of the reason, the padding error actally is a padding error, ie. wrong padding data after decryption. It doesn't mean that everything else is right. And the lib can't even possibly tell if the key was wrong, without MAC etc.

Comment: @zaph 1: The last byte 0 and other bytes with any value can't be true. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5652#section-6.3 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#PKCS7 and it wouldn't even work to detect the length..I still think, given inform distribution for message length, that the probabilty is `(1/16)*((1/256)^16 + (1/256)^15 + ... + (1/256)^1)`

Comment: `The cause of the bad padding is not that the incorrect padding was added during encryption` Yeah, and I never said it was. And again, how do you think the library should detect a wrong key without MAC etc.? If it is "padding error" or "The padding bytes have unexpected values" imho doesn't really matter, the developer should understand it.

Comment: So, is it a good idea to put some know data (ie. 32 bytes of 0x00) at the beginning or the end of the data I want to encrypt and at the decryption process, check if this data is what it is supposed to be?

Comment: @zaph 1: You still forgot the /16 (for uniform distribution at least), and then it's not close anymore.  2: Now you're repeating my answer... whatever.

Comment: @lolyman13 Why do you want this? If it's meant to be a reliable detection if the was was wrong: No. Well, in terms of probabilities, it's pretty ok (someone per chance getting 256bit right is similar to  guessing the right AES key). But, don't, just because it's different from a MAC (MessageAuthenticationCode). In some specific situations, your idea is not as secure. One example (not with 0-byte, but with an unencrypted hash): http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/16428/why-is-plain-hash-then-encrypt-not-a-secure-mac

Comment: `What you are ignoring that [a byte can have 256 values]` I'm not ignoring that... and it's funny that you are posting me a link I posted for you before, as well as explaining the formula part we both posted before. Did you even read my comment with the formula above? I did these calculations too ... well, whatever. About the padding oracle, you mentioned that before too, and it doesn't change the probability part.

Comment: And I think, as long as the text of the main answer above isn't wrong, we can stop this discussion (?) now.

Comment: Incorrect decryption such as with an incorrect key the padding bytes can take on all values: 0-255. You have to ask what is the probability of each of the 16 valid PKCS#7 paddings. The most common is one pad character of 0x00, that has a 1/256 chance. The next most common would be two bytes of padding of 0x02, 0x02 and the probability is 1/256 * 1/256. Things become more improbable as the number of pad bytes increase.

Comment: The point is: 1. Using a [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7) error to determine if a decryption is incorrect is not reliable and reliability is required. 2. Returning an error due to a padding error when using CBC mode is a security error, that creates a [Padding Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_oracle_attack).

Comment: @lolyman-  *"... is it a good idea to put some know data (ie. 32 bytes of 0x00) at the beginning or the end of the data..."* - Usually not. You usually use an [Authenticated Encryption](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Authenticated_Encryption) mode.